# After update in magento 2.4 all require js file not working

Tags: magento, magento2.4

Due to update to Magento 2.4, changes were made by the developer in the vendor's Magento theme.
require js is not working.

Before it loading all js
[image]

I have made all the changes as before and after that not loading all JS as expected.

[image]

I have run below commands

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

but no effect.